# Como conectar una API de proveedor GPS a Google Cloud

Tags: api

Cual es la API a utilizar de la biblioteca de API Google Cloud para conectar

http://apigps.gpschile.com:28080/actividad/service/v1/public/receptores/689/dispositivos/actividad

Comment: Es una API para extraer datos GPS de mi flota de camiones.

Comment: ¿Puedes ser más claro y agregar el código que intentaste? Para eso [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/578386/edit) la pregunta.